# R shiny: Error in handler(binary, message) : No handler registered...matrix

Tags: r, shiny

I decided to reproduce the html code of the following link (because I would like to change it slightly):
http://spark.rstudio.com/gsdesign/matrix/

I copy-pasted it in my file:static_temp.html

Since the code includes tableinput.css and tableinput.js, I downloaded these files and inserted them in my folder with ui.R, server.R and static_temp.html.

When I run it with the ui.R and server.R herebelow, it gives this error and the page becomes grey (but usable):

**Error in handler(binary, message) : 
  No handler registered for for type enrollRates:matrix**

Here is the ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("test"),
sidebarPanel(
),
mainPanel(
includeHTML("static_temp.html")
)
))
```

And the server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
}
)
```

Any suggestion/advice would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because `tableinput.css` and `tableinput.js` are in your directory but they aren't used.

In static_temp.html in the head tag add :

```
<script src="tableinput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tableinput.css"/>
```

OR in your Ui.R :

```
tags$head(tags$script(src = "tableinput.js"))
tags$head(tags$link(rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="tableinput.css"))
```